# Collision detection on sub views contained in 2 separate parent UIViews?

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiview

I originally setup some conditions using CGRectIntersectsRect for some collision detection which worked fine.  In the greater scale of things I only need part of the view to be detected.

So originally within the ViewController it was comparing 2 UIviews.

Now what I need to do is collision detection of subViews within 2 different UIViews that are contained in a view in which the view controller does the logic.

My script is no longer working as I suspect CGRectIntersectsRect only compares frames within the same view?  I'll keep digging to confirm this.

Any ways around this?  Is it possible for example to get the x and y pos of the sub view in relation to the main view that's performing the logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use UIView's `convertRect:toView:` or `convertRect:fromView:` (or the point equivalents) to get them in the same coordinate space.